# How to Use IF Condition?

Tags: email, powershell, if-statement

My requirement is, the script needs to be sent an email to set of people whenever application pool recycled. Script will search for application pool event IDs from Event Viewer and will send an email if it find any events. If it's found the Event ID it will create an log file in D:\temp and send that log file to recipients.

The problem is, the script is sending an email with empty log file as attachment when no events happen. I dont want to send empty file and script should sent **ONLY** when event occurs. This can be resolved if we use an `if` condition, but not sure how to use that in my script.

Below is the script which I used to run. Currently it is sending log when events occur and not occur as well.

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss"

$starttime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)

Get-WinEvent -ComputerName computer1 -Filterhashtable @{
    LogName='system';
    StartTime=$StartTime;
    ID=3201,5079,2262,2263,5070,5074,5075,5076,5077,5078,5080,5081,5093,5117,5186
  } |
  select machinename,timecreated,id,message |
  Format-Table machinename,timecreated,id,message -AutoSize |
  Out-String -Width 6096 |
  Out-File "D:\Logs\PS\$date.txt" -NoClobber

Send-MailMessage -To user1@test.com `
  -Subject "Application Pool Recycled in Computer1" `
  -Body "Application Pool has Recycled in Computer1" `
  -SmtpServer smtp.com `
  -From Apppool_Monitoring@test.com `
  -Attachments "D:\Logs\PS\$date.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you actually got an event before creating output and sending mail:

```
$evt = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName computer1 -Filterhashtable @{...}
if ($evt) {
  $evt | Format-Table ... |
    Out-String -Width 6096 |
    Out-File "D:\Logs\PS\$date.txt" -NoClobber

  Send-MailMessage ...
}
```

If you want the message inline instead of as an attachment put the event string in a variable and put that in the message body:

```
if ($evt) {
  $msg = $evt | Format-Table ... | Out-String -Width 6096

  Send-MailMessage ... -Body "Application Pool has Recycled in Computer1`n$msg" ...
}
```

Comment: @Kiran & Ansgar, is there any way. instead of sending as attachment, Can we post the output in email body ?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, It is working. I just done some little change. I used "Application Pool has Recycled in Computer1`n $msg" instead of using "Application Pool has Recycled in Computer1`n`n$msg". With `n`n$msg i didn't get output in email body.

Answer (score 1):

read the contents of the logfile..if the log file contains data then send email otherwise do nothing.

```
if(Get-Content -Path "D:\Logs\PS\$date.txt")
{
  #send email.......
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kiran. I have tried this one it perfectly working. It is reading Content of the file, if nothing is there then it is not sending an email. if some content is there then it is sending an email.